# How to dynamically populate an environment variable value in a Postman attachment

Tags: postman

I am making a series of API calls using Postman. I need to use a value from API response #1 in API request #2. The trick is that the value must be placed in a file attachment.

More details:
I create a transaction in my first API call and a transaction ID is returned in the response.
I have no problem taking the transaction ID from response #1 and placing it an environment variable, and I know how to use the environment variable in subsequent calls by placing my variable in the Body as form-data:

[image: form-data]

What I am struggling to figure out is how to take my transaction ID and use it in XML that is an attachment to my API call.

[image: XML attachment]

I cannot simply insert a variable into the stored XML file (e.g., `transactionSid="{{tSid}}"` within my XML returns an error when I call the API).

Is it possible to use an environment variable in a file attachment in Postman or otherwise dynamically insert my environment variable into the request?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly do it , you have write a custom api that wraps the file and make the changes.

use express to create a simple api :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs');
const args = require('yargs').argv;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json())

const port = args.port || 3000;

data = []

app.listen(port, '127.0.0.1', console.log(`The api service have started at port ${port} , \n `));

app.get('/modifyXml', (req, res) => {

    //write logic to modify xml file and send it back
    res.send(req.body)


});
```

Comment: Very useful simple hack.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give you an upvote for your answer, but although the previous commenter called this a "simple hack" it's beyond my current level of knowledge so I'll have a hard time making this work. I'll give it a shot, though, and if it pans out I'll apply the checkmark to your answer.